# How to pass model value in thymeleaf input text

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have data in a Model object and I want to put that into the input field in my Thymeleaf template, such that if the value is null, nothing will be displayed and otherwise, the input will have the value inside it. I tried this but this is not working.

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First" value=${accountInfo.firstName} maxlength=31 required>
```

I passed the values into the model object inside the java exception handler like so:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=SignupFormException.class)
public String handle(HttpSession session, SignupFormException ex, Model response) {

    response.addAttribute("accountInfo", (Account) session.getAttribute("accountToRegister"));
    response.addAttribute("Error", ex.getMessage());
    session.invalidate();

    return "redirect:/signup";

}
```

How to fetch the attributes from the accountInfo object I passed in my model in my thymeleaf template?

**Update:**
Now it is working but not the first time the page is accessed when there is no model object. Following is the code:

My thymeleaf form:

```
<form action="/signup_do" th:object="${accountInfo}" method="post">
    <input id="first_name" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First" th:value=*{firstName} maxlength=31 required>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/signup_do")
public String register(Account account, HttpSession session) {

    session.setAttribute("accountToRegister", account);
    accountManagement.accountRegistration(account);

    return "Success";
}
```

There is a account registration service that throws SignupFormException which is handled by:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=SignupFormException.class)
public String handle(HttpSession session, SignupFormException ex, Model response) {

    response.addAttribute("accountInfo", (Account) session.getAttribute("accountToRegister"));
    response.addAttribute("Error", ex.getMessage());
    session.invalidate();

    return "redirect:/signup";

}
```

And only now do I have a model object with properties for the thymeleaf template...

Answer (score 0):

change `"value"` to `"th:field"`

OR

change `"value"` to `th:value="${accountInfo.firstName}"`

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/yourURL}" th:object="${accountInfo}" method="post">                      
     <input id="first_name" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First" th:field=*{firstName} maxlength=31 required>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this throws exception: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor

Comment: Hello @YeetCoder which one gives this error? Have you tried with both

Comment: The th:field does not work, but if I change that to th:value, it works, but throws null exception. The thing is the first time I access the page, there is no model object, and after the user signs up and an exception occurs then the model object is sent back. Is there some way to only access the firstName if accountInfo is not null?

Comment: Hello @YeetCoder, can you share your related code, it will be helpful

Comment: @YeetCoder change  `return "redirect:/signup";` to  `return "redirect:/signup_do";` in execption handler, here last class